PHP function check if Coordinates are inside a polygon defined by an array of coordinates
I have this function which check if coordinates passed as array e.g [42.4694321,-93.8159149] fall inside a polygon defined by a multidimentional array for coordinates as below:
[
    [
        -96.3535692803233,
        42.4906484122099
    ],
    [
        -96.3552682810882,
        42.4904364119476
    ],
    [
        -96.3563672818034,
        42.4903134124502
    ],
    [
        -96.3566792810746,
        42.4902754126213
    ],
    [
        -96.3580912817843,
        42.4901544126285
    ],
    [
        -96.3585032824112,
        42.4901334121844
    ],
    [
        -96.3589812822621,
        42.4901204123475
    ],
    [
        -96.3591972821722,
        42.4901154117981
    ],
    [
        -96.3597362821225,
        42.4900904116946
    ],
    [
        -96.3600832824521,
        42.4900864120481
    ],
    [
        -96.360896282937,
        42.4901194121052
    ],
    [
        -96.3614932826136,
        42.4901214119274
    ],
    [
        -96.3619932831041,
        42.4901244119919
    ],
    [
        -96.3624312836704,
        42.4901204123475
    ],
    [
        -96.3627862834976,
        42.490126411814
    ],
    [
        -96.3630542832862,
        42.4901304121204
    ],
    [
        -96.3634762839589,
        42.490128411636
    ],
    [
        -96.3635972834344,
        42.4901284122984
    ],
    [
        -96.3639912836197,
        42.4901344117641
    ],
    [
        -96.3645482840116,
        42.4901414121336
    ],
    [
        -96.3651932833688,
        42.4901474115981
    ],
    [
        -96.3657752838751,
        42.4901524114825
    ],
    [
        -96.3663742840998,
        42.490157412029
    ],
    [
        -96.366480284405,
        42.4901584116083
    ],
    [
        -96.3681892852156,
        42.4901734112578
    ],
    [
        -96.3689632844442,
        42.4901794113816
    ],
    [
        -96.3698182847619,
        42.4901864110837
    ],
    [
        -96.3701542843226,
        42.4901894118074
    ],
    [
        -96.3707382844787,
        42.4901944116885
    ],
    [
        -96.3713722848635,
        42.4902004118103
    ],
    [
        -96.3715242851994,
        42.4902004111479
    ],
    [
        -96.3730982862908,
        42.4902034112085
    ],
    [
        -96.3743812853324,
        42.4902064106066
    ],
    [
        -96.3745172866732,
        42.4902074108476
    ],
    [
        -96.3759202862637,
        42.4902424106592
    ],
    [
        -96.3773692867833,
        42.4902784113535
    ],
    [
        -96.3773692867833,
        42.490226411448
    ],
    [
        -96.3773692867833,
        42.4899494110829
    ],
    [
        -96.3773702875065,
        42.4898354108632
    ],
    [
        -96.3779292875483,
        42.489845411344
    ],
    [
        -96.3786152869133,
        42.489849411006
    ],
    [
        -96.3796812880166,
        42.4898574103291
    ],
    [
        -96.3799582871277,
        42.4899224110844
    ],
    [
        -96.3801352866797,
        42.4899174105192
    ],
    [
        -96.3801272871821,
        42.4902254112074
    ],
    [
        -96.3801262873572,
        42.4902504112569
    ],
    [
        -96.3800742874786,
        42.4904224106114
    ],
    [
        -96.3799792879424,
        42.4906344109212
    ],
    [
        -96.3796152878943,
        42.4910164110841
    ],
    [
        -96.3794832885482,
        42.4911544106004
    ],
    [
        -96.3794102878549,
        42.4912194106704
    ],
    [
        -96.3793022878999,
        42.4913474108246
    ],
    [
        -96.3787162871956,
        42.4919464115273
    ],
    [
        -96.3784832875671,
        42.4922144111055
    ],
    [
        -96.3783462872998,
        42.4924664115595
    ],
    [
        -96.3782552879615,
        42.492744410914
    ],
    [
        -96.3782542872383,
        42.4930574112435
    ],
    [
        -96.378264287284,
        42.4932404116205
    ],
    [
        -96.378300287269,
        42.4940624113895
    ],
    [
        -96.3783032876421,
        42.4943614112923
    ],
    [
        -96.3783242884568,
        42.4953294117674
    ],
    [
        -96.3783212871854,
        42.4954154121372
    ],
    [
        -96.3783112871397,
        42.4958284116343
    ],
    [
        -96.3783092883882,
        42.4958794113686
    ],
    [
        -96.3783322879544,
        42.4964474119876
    ],
    [
        -96.3783322879544,
        42.4965504118691
    ],
    [
        -96.3784762878944,
        42.4965504118691
    ],
    [
        -96.3786392881011,
        42.4965504112067
    ],
    [
        -96.3796452880315,
        42.4965264118282
    ],
    [
        -96.3798302879795,
        42.4965124118554
    ],
    [
        -96.3800502880875,
        42.4964954121206
    ],
    [
        -96.3802862880891,
        42.4964924116994
    ],
    [
        -96.3811992890314,
        42.4964864115189
    ],
    [
        -96.3829802889137,
        42.4964804120002
    ],
    [
        -96.3841302896826,
        42.4964764114376
    ],
    [
        -96.3856502903473,
        42.4964724115371
    ],
    [
        -96.3859062904403,
        42.496475411297
    ],
    [
        -96.3874112910364,
        42.4964904114185
    ],
    [
        -96.3877802911073,
        42.4964944106556
    ],
    [
        -96.3879702910781,
        42.4964934111775
    ],
    [
        -96.3882162902271,
        42.4964924116994
    ],
    [
        -96.3886822903824,
        42.496491411559
    ],
    [
        -96.3888762905512,
        42.496491411559
    ],
    [
        -96.3891952903934,
        42.4964894112781
    ],
    [
        -96.3893482914526,
        42.4964884111376
    ],
    [
        -96.3907312909517,
        42.4964654112139
    ],
    [
        -96.391153290726,
        42.4964674114956
    ],
    [
        -96.3913152911077,
        42.496468410974
    ],
    [
        -96.3916252907291,
        42.4964704105932
    ],
    [
        -96.3918312914918,
        42.4964724115371
    ],
    [
        -96.3920282911353,
        42.4964734110155
    ],
    [
        -96.3923242914113,
        42.4964764114376
    ],
    [
        -96.39244629161,
        42.4975134109579
    ],
    [
        -96.3920632912954,
        42.4985434110736
    ],
    [
        -96.3920862926582,
        42.5006094118525
    ],
    [
        -96.3921012927268,
        42.5013264115415
    ],
    [
        -96.3920942930542,
        42.5017774112236
    ],
    [
        -96.3921012918285,
        42.501899411301
    ],
    [
        -96.3921232924682,
        42.5023064120633
    ],
    [
        -96.3921642933743,
        42.5025564121634
    ],
    [
        -96.3921662921259,
        42.5028774120368
    ],
    [
        -96.3921682917757,
        42.5032644117541
    ],
    [
        -96.3922072930321,
        42.5038334122041
    ],
    [
        -96.3922202925525,
        42.5039104119416
    ],
    [
        -96.3922962936188,
        42.5043754123922
    ],
    [
        -96.3923322927055,
        42.5046424123397
    ],
    [
        -96.3923412929263,
        42.5048064124515
    ],
    [
        -96.3923472927742,
        42.5051134119971
    ],
    [
        -96.3923632926677,
        42.5060304122327
    ],
    [
        -96.392341292028,
        42.5064424124988
    ],
    [
        -96.3922302934966,
        42.5069904124192
    ],
    [
        -96.3920562934193,
        42.5074714125777
    ],
    [
        -96.3920362933278,
        42.5075274125691
    ],
    [
        -96.3918442928089,
        42.5079464132656
    ],
    [
        -96.3915772937435,
        42.5087484128808
    ],
    [
        -96.3914682921669,
        42.5089724126046
    ],
    [
        -96.3913492932396,
        42.5092184127895
    ],
    [
        -96.3911912930558,
        42.5095434126181
    ],
    [
        -96.3910692937554,
        42.5097634130915
    ],
    [
        -96.3909682925748,
        42.5099474128446
    ],
    [
        -96.3906872923674,
        42.510452413429
    ],
    [
        -96.390340292936,
        42.5110764135651
    ],
    [
        -96.3898322929479,
        42.511641412849
    ],
    [
        -96.3887172923392,
        42.5126084134505
    ],
    [
        -96.3874762931304,
        42.5137134143778
    ],
    [
        -96.3863632921714,
        42.5147224143284
    ],
    [
        -96.3853252924539,
        42.5155324137541
    ],
    [
        -96.3846132922513,
        42.5161094137153
    ],
    [
        -96.3835212921071,
        42.5169514143537
    ],
    [
        -96.3826292919794,
        42.517511414476
    ],
    [
        -96.3823172909115,
        42.5177074148561
    ],
    [
        -96.3820072921885,
        42.517861415149
    ],
    [
        -96.381687291623,
        42.5180214151632
    ],
    [
        -96.3814862917816,
        42.5181584142166
    ],
    [
        -96.3809002910773,
        42.5185564156495
    ],
    [
        -96.3803862912414,
        42.5190124150668
    ],
    [
        -96.3802242908597,
        42.5191904154115
    ],
    [
        -96.3797742914962,
        42.5196854151254
    ],
    [
        -96.3789152909805,
        42.5209524153511
    ],
    [
        -96.3782822904206,
        42.5218414157543
    ],
    [
        -96.3775392920525,
        42.5229274157042
    ],
    [
        -96.3768932919721,
        42.523929415949
    ],
    [
        -96.3760942908326,
        42.5251144164452
    ],
    [
        -96.3760762912892,
        42.5251414164746
    ],
    [
        -96.3754402903563,
        42.5260554164921
    ],
    [
        -96.375240291238,
        42.5263574166327
    ],
    [
        -96.3747522913414,
        42.5270944165531
    ],
    [
        -96.3732532905931,
        42.5293204166298
    ],
    [
        -96.3725812905735,
        42.5302884173234
    ],
    [
        -96.3719892900214,
        42.5311554171215
    ],
    [
        -96.371492289904,
        42.5319124174466
    ],
    [
        -96.3714462898732,
        42.5319824173587
    ],
    [
        -96.3709842899159,
        42.5325944175984
    ],
    [
        -96.3705482907961,
        42.5330904172437
    ],
    [
        -96.3701182906258,
        42.5334974181235
    ],
    [
        -96.3697622909736,
        42.5337964180753
    ],
    [
        -96.3692092907797,
        42.5341944185198
    ],
    [
        -96.3689272907474,
        42.5343994179737
    ],
    [
        -96.3679642895763,
        42.5350204180474
    ],
    [
        -96.3667672898501,
        42.5358044185776
    ],
    [
        -96.3639332901816,
        42.537627419458
    ],
    [
        -96.3625292889695,
        42.5385374196037
    ],
    [
        -96.3624002890981,
        42.5386214191828
    ],
    [
        -96.3608472888214,
        42.5396354192284
    ],
    [
        -96.3604902893444,
        42.5398644193119
    ],
    [
        -96.3593232879588,
        42.5406154200595
    ],
    [
        -96.3568912879732,
        42.5421764198722
    ],
    [
        -96.3555422870128,
        42.5430614204695
    ],
    [
        -96.3544512875918,
        42.5437634209056
    ],
    [
        -96.3528742870257,
        42.5447824209852
    ],
    [
        -96.3512352865353,
        42.5458484215837
    ],
    [
        -96.3505312867286,
        42.5462974209539
    ],
    [
        -96.3502842868564,
        42.5464544209297
    ],
    [
        -96.3500942859873,
        42.5465764211526
    ],
    [
        -96.3487692862145,
        42.5474334212925
    ],
    [
        -96.3482282866145,
        42.5477904216302
    ],
    [
        -96.3474152861295,
        42.548326421273
    ],
    [
        -96.3462022865098,
        42.5491644219865
    ],
    [
        -96.3456062857598,
        42.5496054217119
    ],
    [
        -96.343062284723,
        42.5516994230847
    ],
    [
        -96.342162285996,
        42.5524264220088
    ],
    [
        -96.3416992844171,
        42.5528204232187
    ],
    [
        -96.3413302852445,
        42.5531334224928
    ],
    [
        -96.3411862853044,
        42.5532554228967
    ],
    [
        -96.34027728456,
        42.553996423221
    ],
    [
        -96.340140285191,
        42.5541074232567
    ],
    [
        -96.3397512850285,
        42.5544304227681
    ],
    [
        -96.3389252850231,
        42.5551154227352
    ],
    [
        -96.3379742844459,
        42.5558844232986
    ],
    [
        -96.3367602841029,
        42.5568954233584
    ],
    [
        -96.3356452843925,
        42.5578134244335
    ],
    [
        -96.3341212835298,
        42.559088424476
    ],
    [
        -96.332021282907,
        42.5608314247452
    ],
    [
        -96.3320262838282,
        42.5604274247133
    ],
    [
        -96.3320692834859,
        42.5575964238975
    ],
    [
        -96.3321142827934,
        42.5567014245252
    ],
    [
        -96.332104283646,
        42.556226423267
    ],
    [
        -96.3319972826176,
        42.5515854236368
    ],
    [
        -96.3319912827698,
        42.5514664230449
    ],
    [
        -96.3317922816798,
        42.5477654220902
    ],
    [
        -96.3318452813833,
        42.5472814224033
    ],
    [
        -96.3318972812618,
        42.5445934223872
    ],
    [
        -96.3318902815891,
        42.5435974223296
    ],
    [
        -96.3319392810946,
        42.5426084220563
    ],
    [
        -96.3319532813383,
        42.5421264215805
    ],
    [
        -96.3319682805086,
        42.5414684216138
    ],
    [
        -96.3319762809045,
        42.5407984221973
    ],
    [
        -96.3319402800212,
        42.5401934210023
    ],
    [
        -96.3319362807216,
        42.5400374212719
    ],
    [
        -96.3318932810639,
        42.5388284215637
    ],
    [
        -96.3318732809724,
        42.5384574217591
    ],
    [
        -96.3318732809724,
        42.5381244216292
    ],
    [
        -96.332166279977,
        42.5374024216904
    ],
    [
        -96.3321692794517,
        42.5298804197572
    ],
    [
        -96.3322192778838,
        42.5183614183851
    ],
    [
        -96.3322092787364,
        42.5178434187717
    ],
    [
        -96.3322182780589,
        42.5169684184584
    ],
    [
        -96.3322132780361,
        42.5165654184089
    ],
    [
        -96.3322162775108,
        42.5160054177548
    ],
    [
        -96.3322182780589,
        42.515933418158
    ],
    [
        -96.3322282772064,
        42.5155164177026
    ],
    [
        -96.332250277846,
        42.5152724174859
    ],
    [
        -96.3322732783105,
        42.5149364180272
    ],
    [
        -96.3322732783105,
        42.5148714181106
    ],
    [
        -96.33227927726,
        42.5144994178475
    ],
    [
        -96.3323072777474,
        42.5140434172811
    ],
    [
        -96.3323082775723,
        42.5136194177307
    ],
    [
        -96.3322982775265,
        42.5133054178182
    ],
    [
        -96.3322972777016,
        42.5132484171715
    ],
    [
        -96.3323132775952,
        42.5129694170545
    ],
    [
        -96.3323402773594,
        42.5125604177411
    ],
    [
        -96.3323432768341,
        42.512252417798
    ],
    [
        -96.3324432772915,
        42.5121934177367
    ],
    [
        -96.3327092774303,
        42.5124434173675
    ],
    [
        -96.3327152772781,
        42.5122684173336
    ],
    [
        -96.3327242783972,
        42.5120244170172
    ],
    [
        -96.3327562781843,
        42.5111824175388
    ],
    [
        -96.3325102772387,
        42.5052854168324
    ],
    [
        -96.3323452764839,
        42.5052004161306
    ],
    [
        -96.3311482767577,
        42.5045834163536
    ],
    [
        -96.3310512766733,
        42.504516416242
    ],
    [
        -96.3310392760795,
        42.5044324164949
    ],
    [
        -96.3309852765511,
        42.5035064164076
    ],
    [
        -96.3318622757118,
        42.5022074158985
    ],
    [
        -96.3323642767505,
        42.5014114155235
    ],
    [
        -96.3324012756621,
        42.5005174155204
    ],
    [
        -96.3293472758856,
        42.5004754162861
    ],
    [
        -96.329328275619,
        42.4994964156371
    ],
    [
        -96.3293152743019,
        42.4987424156157
    ],
    [
        -96.3323832752204,
        42.4986744157624
    ],
    [
        -96.3323652756771,
        42.4967284145889
    ],
    [
        -96.3323382750146,
        42.4937804138466
    ],
    [
        -96.3323342757149,
        42.4933594145356
    ],
    [
        -96.3323592758293,
        42.4933464147068
    ],
    [
        -96.3325742759144,
        42.493231415187
    ],
    [
        -96.3327282759002,
        42.4931664145585
    ],
    [
        -96.333615276005,
        42.4928554145093
    ],
    [
        -96.3342022756359,
        42.4926494149905
    ],
    [
        -96.3343252756595,
        42.4926064142433
    ],
    [
        -96.3357932764457,
        42.4921384143967
    ],
    [
        -96.3361102766381,
        42.4920454140016
    ],
    [
        -96.3365412766333,
        42.4919504137045
    ],
    [
        -96.3373542762199,
        42.4917604140022
    ],
    [
        -96.3378422761166,
        42.4916694141426
    ],
    [
        -96.3382342757537,
        42.4915894139091
    ],
    [
        -96.338751276861,
        42.4914844133646
    ],
    [
        -96.3403122766353,
        42.4911454138669
    ],
    [
        -96.3410162773403,
        42.4910004133957
    ],
    [
        -96.3413842775863,
        42.490913413349
    ],
    [
        -96.3417972771399,
        42.490844413363
    ],
    [
        -96.3420642771036,
        42.4908134134885
    ],
    [
        -96.342308277501,
        42.4907904134649
    ],
    [
        -96.3425832778606,
        42.4907824135986
    ],
    [
        -96.3430312784726,
        42.4907834138304
    ],
    [
        -96.3433822781019,
        42.490801413362
    ],
    [
        -96.3436522784386,
        42.490828412981
    ],
    [
        -96.3437572780206,
        42.4908384139654
    ],
    [
        -96.3444902781396,
        42.4909114128897
    ],
    [
        -96.3456912780638,
        42.4910344131983
    ],
    [
        -96.3464952792262,
        42.4911004129572
    ],
    [
        -96.3468562797996,
        42.4911164126072
    ],
    [
        -96.3471772783933,
        42.4911164132696
    ],
    [
        -96.3476382794241,
        42.4911094130092
    ],
    [
        -96.3478232784737,
        42.4910974129395
    ],
    [
        -96.3480212788404,
        42.4910774137015
    ],
    [
        -96.3482762791085,
        42.4910464126176
    ],
    [
        -96.3490952785429,
        42.4909274132505
    ],
    [
        -96.3495752798403,
        42.4908634131075
    ],
    [
        -96.3498732797661,
        42.4908144130573
    ],
    [
        -96.3503402806447,
        42.4907584126691
    ],
    [
        -96.3505342799151,
        42.4907434131598
    ],
    [
        -96.3510362800554,
        42.4907244127164
    ],
    [
        -96.3518292804489,
        42.4907224129135
    ],
    [
        -96.3523522805056,
        42.4907284129846
    ],
    [
        -96.3528582799456,
        42.4907074127332
    ],
    [
        -96.3531272804574,
        42.4906934121201
    ],
    [
        -96.353410281213,
        42.49066841291
    ],
    [
        -96.3535692803233,
        42.4906484122099
    ]
]

Here is my code which doesnt seem to produce correct results:
public function isPointInPolygon($point, $polygon) {
        $x = $point[0];
        $y = $point[1];
        $inside = false;
        $n = count($polygon);
        $j = $n - 1;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
            if (($polygon[$i][1] < $y && $polygon[$j][1] >= $y || $polygon[$j][1] < $y && $polygon[$i][1] >= $y) &&
                ($polygon[$i][0] + ($y - $polygon[$i][1]) / ($polygon[$j][1] - $polygon[$i][1]) * ($polygon[$j][0] - $polygon[$i][0]) < $x)) {
                $inside = !$inside;
            }
            $j = $i;
        }

        return $inside; 


    } 

What could be the issue? I have checked other threads/questions but none is helping

all the points are the same?

I only duplicated them for the question, but the ones I am passing to the function are different @Randy

see here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon/#  chi suma!

Does not have PHP

no php, but a correct algorithm

"I only duplicated them for the question" - Is there a reason you can't post some coordinates for us to test? I don't know a polygon's worth of them off the top of my head. Also can you post samples of calling this that should both pass and fail? These steps will all lead to hopefully helping people give you answers.

@ChrisHaas I have updated the question with correct polygon coordinates

First, I assume you mean [-93.8159149, 42.4694321] and not [42.4694321,-93.8159149]. Second, all longitudes in the provided sample polygon start with -96, and I'd be surprised if something that starts with -93 would be inside of it. I confirmed this by plotting the polygon here, then re-plotting it and adding the test point, and it was way far out. Third, when building this, I think it would be much easier to test if you had simple sample data, maybe just a polygon of 5 or 10 points.

I'm not saying your function is right or wrong, but given the provided polygon and the provided point, I'd expect the function to return false which it does. I did not try to find a point inside of the polygon to test for true.

You really should create test polygon with a handful of coordinates where it is easy to verify the solution. Also, strictly based on how concise the algorithm you're using is, I'm going to guess that it only works for convex hulls, and the huge set of coordinates in your example polygon may well describe a shape with concave inclusions. You've also not specified the name of the algorithm you're using, so there's now way that we can comment on if your implementation is correct.
